# array sort problem with running time in worst case of Θ(n)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

> Given an array A with n − 1  numbers, where n = 2^k
> for some integer k. One of the values appears exactly n/2 times, another appears exactly n/4 times and so on. More formally, for all 1 ≤ k ≤ log n, there exists a unique value that appears exactly n/(2^k) times, and the numbers stored in the array can be of any size.
> Describe an algorithm that sorts A with a worst-case run-time complexity of Θ(n), in Java.
> Example:
> Input: 5, 1, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5
> Output: 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5

I have a hard time adjusting it to be in worst case Θ(n).

I tried with HashTable but quickly realized inserting and *contains* in HashTable has an expected running time of Θ(n), since then I am stuck.

Comment: Any restriction on the values? For O(n) I think your best bet is to look at some sort of radix sort, if the values are integral (and possibly using a value/count pair). If there's some way to take advantage of the logarithmic value distribution, I'm not clever enough to see that.

Comment: @JohnBayko No the values can be whatever, I think using the different appearances is the key but not sure how

Comment: Inserting and `contains()` in a `HashTable` have an expected running time of *O(1),*  not *O(n).* However you are asked to 'describe an algorithm', not write code involving existing data structures.

Answer (score 0):

(What is `HashTable`?
Sadly, `java.util.Hashtable` still isn't deprecated.)

Establish the count of each array value, e.g. using a `java.util.Map`.
If you had the unique values (`Map` keys) ordered, how could you enumerate the array values with correct multiplicity?
How many different values are there?